# Unable to get stat gathering to work

Tags: php

Using PHP to gather stats from multiple files. Goal is to take the entire first row of data, which is the column name, then take the entire row of data from the row where the first column matches the name specified in the code. These two rows should then be linked to each other, so they can be displayed in a dynamic image.

However, to avoid excessive requests from the external data source, the data is only downloaded once a day by saving it into a json file. The previous day's data is also kept, to perform a difference calculation.

What I'm stuck on is...well, it's not working as intended. The dynamic image does not display and says it cannot be displayed because it contains errors, and the files aren't being created properly. Without any files existing, only the 'old' data file is being created, and the gathered data is saved there in a format that I didn't expect.

Here's the entire PHP code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type:image/png");
    $root=realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    function saveTeamData(){
        $urls=array('http://www.dc-vault.com/stats/bio.txt','http://www.dc-vault.com/stats/math.txt','http://www.dc-vault.com/stats/misc.txt','http://www.dc-vault.com/stats/overall.txt','http://www.dc-vault.com/stats/phys.txt');
        $fullJson=array();
        function stats($url){
            $json=array();
            $team=array("teamName");
            $file=fopen($url,'r');
            $firstRow=fgetcsv($file,0,"\t");
            while($data=fgetcsv($file,0,"\t")){
                if(in_array($data[0],$team)){
                    foreach($firstRow as $indx=>$colName){

                        if((strpos($colName,'Position')!=0)||(strpos($colName,'Score')!=0)||(strpos($colName,'Team')!=0)){
                            if(strrpos($colName,'Position')!==false){
                                $colName=substr($colName,0,strpos($colName,' Position'));
                                $colName=$colName."Pos";
                            }else{
                                $colName=substr($colName,0,strpos($colName,' Score'));
                                $colName=$colName."Score";
                            }
                            $colName=str_replace(' ',',',$colName);
                            $teamData[$colName]=$data[$indx];
                        }
                    }
                    $json=$teamData;
                }
            }
            fclose($file);
            return $json;
        }
        foreach($urls as $item){
            $fullJson=array_merge($fullJson,stats($item));
        }
        $final_json['teamName']=$fullJson;
        $final_json['date']=date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime("11:00"));
        $final_json=json_encode($final_json);
        file_put_contents("$root/scripts/vaultData.js",$final_json);
        return $final_json;
    }
    if(!file_exists("$root/scripts/vaultData.js")){
        $teamData=saveTeamData();
    }else{
        $teamData=json_decode(file_get_contents("$root/scripts/vaultData.js"));
    }
    $lastDate=$teamData->date;
    $now=date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
    $hours=(strtotime($now)-strtotime($lastDate))/3600;
    if($hours>=24||!file_exists("$root/scripts/vaultDataOld.js")){
        file_put_contents("$root/scripts/vaultDataOld.js",json_encode($teamData));
        $teamData=saveTeamData();
    }
    $team=$teamData->{"teamName"};
    $teamOld=json_decode(file_get_contents("$root/scripts/vaultDataOld.js"))->{"teamName"};
    $template=imagecreatefrompng("$root/images/vaultInfo.png");
    $black=imagecolorallocate($template,0,0,0);
    $font='images/fonts/UbuntuMono-R.ttf';
    $projects=array();
    $subsections=array();
    foreach($team as $key=>$val){
        $projectName=preg_match("/^(.*)(?:Pos|Score)$/",$key,$cap);
        $projectName=str_replace(","," ",$cap[1]);
        if(preg_match("/Pos/",$key)){
            $$key=(strlen($val)>10?substr($val,0,10):$val);
            $delta=$key."Delta";
            $$delta=($val - $teamOld->{$key});
            $$delta=(strlen($$delta)>5?substr($$delta,0,5):$$delta);
            if($projectName!=="Overall"){
                if(!in_array($projectName,array("Physical Science","Bio/Med Science","Mathematics","Miscellaneous"))){
                    $projects[$projectName]["position"]=$$key;
                    $projects[$projectName]["position delta"]=$$delta*1;
                }else{
                    $subsections[$projectName]["position"]=$$key;
                    $subsections[$projectName]["position delta"]=$$delta*1;
                }
            }
        }elseif(preg_match("/Score/",$key)){
            $$key=(strlen($val)>10?substr($val,0,10):$val);
            $delta=$key."Delta";
            $$delta=($val - $teamOld->{$key});
            $$delta=(strlen($$delta)>9?substr($$delta,0,9):$$delta);
            if($projectName!=="Overall"){
                if(!in_array($projectName,array("Physical Science","Bio/Med Science","Mathematics","Miscellaneous"))){
                    $projects[$projectName]["score"]=$$key;
                    $projects[$projectName]["score delta"]=$$delta;
                }else{
                    $subsections[$projectName]["score"]=$$key;
                    $subsections[$projectName]["score delta"]=$$delta;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $sort=array();
    foreach($projects as $key=>$row){
        $sort[$key]=$row["score"];
    }
    array_multisort($sort,SORT_DESC,$projects);
    $lastupdated=round($hours,2).' hours ago';
    $y=35;
    foreach($projects as $name=>$project){
        imagettftext($template,10,0,5,$y,$black,$font,$name);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,149,$y,$black,$font,$project['position']);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,216,$y,$black,$font,$project['position delta']*-1);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,257,$y,$black,$font,$project['score']);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,331,$y,$black,$font,$project['score delta']);
        $y+=20;
    }
    $y=655;
    foreach($subsections as $name=>$subsection){
        imagettftext($template,10,0,5,$y,$black,$font,$name);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,149,$y,$black,$font,$subsection['position']);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,216,$y,$black,$font,$subsection['position delta']*-1);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,257,$y,$black,$font,$subsection['score']);
        imagettftext($template,10,0,331,$y,$black,$font,$subsection['score delta']);
        $y+=20;
    }
    imagettftext($template,10,0,149,735,$black,$font,$team->{'OverallPos'});
    imagettftext($template,10,0,216,735,$black,$font,$OverallPosDelta*-1);
    imagettftext($template,10,0,257,735,$black,$font,$OverallScore);
    imagettftext($template,10,0,331,735,$black,$font,$OverallScoreDelta);
    imagettftext($template,10,0,149,755,$black,$font,$lastupdated);
    imagepng($template);
?>
```

And here is what the data looks like when it is saved:

```
"{\"teamName\":{\"Folding@HomePos\":\"51\",\"Folding@HomeScore\":\"9994.405407\"},\"date\":\"2014-03-14 11:00:00\"}"
```

I've omitted most of the data because it just makes things excessively long, and it helps to see the format. Now the reason why its an unexpected output is because I didn't expect trailing slashes to be in it. The older version of this code would output like this:

```
{"teamName":{"Asteroids@HomePos":"192","Asteroids@HomeScore":"7647.783251"},"date":"2014-03-14 11:00:00"}
```

So the expected behaviour is to to gather the data from the aforementioned rows in each tab delimited text file, copy the old data into the 'old' data file (vaultDataold), save the new data into the 'current' data file (vaultData), and then display the data from the 'current' file in a dynamic image, along with performing a 'new' minus 'old' calculation on the two files to show the change since the previous day.

Most of this code should work, as I've had it working before in a different way. The issue likely lies somewhere with gathering the row data and saving it, most probably the latter. I'm guessing the slashes are causing the issue.

Comment: add $root in your function ->function saveTeamData($root) add inside too which you call again

Comment: Okay, that helped a little. It's creating the 'current' file and in the right output (ie, without the slashes). The 'old' file still contains the slashes, though, and the image still doesn't display (though again, that could be from the old file's slashes).

Comment: did you add $root in function too? you call saveTeamData() twice in your function

Comment: @aseferov Apologies for the very late reply. My computer died and I only recently got a replacement. Anyway, I found out why the slashes were being added. In my function, I was encoding the JSON contents, so basically I was encoding encoded data. That has fixed my issue. I have other issues, but I'll save them for another question if I haven't made any progress fixing them. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the cause was twofold. Firstly, in my function, I was JSON encoding something that had already been encoded, so when the second file was saved, it appeared as shown in my question. To fix that, I did this:

```
$final_json['date']=date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime("11:00"));
$encode_json=json_encode($final_json);
file_put_contents("$root/scripts/vaultData.js",$encode_json);
return $final_json;
```

In addition, as pointed out by another in the comments, I had to add $root to my function, and again within it.